# How can I disable default apache server in Big Sur?

Tags: apache-http-server

Macs annoyingly come with a default httpd server installed. How can I disable that permanently?

Comment: Do you mean [prevent it launching - clue launchctl](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119674/disable-apache-autostart/119678) or something else?

Comment: I mean decapitate it. Chop it's wobbly bits off. Post it to Timbuktu. Bury it six-feet under. Send it into the distant past in a time machine. Divorce it. Shoot it in the head. Disintegrate it with a nuclear bomb.